# Unwanted modification in State variable (Hook), due to manipulation of local variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const file = [{ id: 1, description: "Test Data" }];

  useEffect(() => setData(file), []);

  const manipulateData = (data) => {
    let tempArray = [...data];
    tempArray.map((item) => delete item.id);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Testing Data</h1>
      {manipulateData(data)}
      {console.log(data)}
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to make modification to the local variable "*tempArray*", and the changes shall not reflect in the variable "*data*"

Comment: Instead of: `setData(file)` try: `setData([...file.map(x => ({...x}))])` and same way: `let tempArray = [...data.map(x => ({...x}))];`. I think it is due to shallow-copy.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are creating a new array, but the `objects` in that array are not deeply copied. Instead, they represent just a reference to the very same objects as in data.

Because both references are pointing at the same object, if you delete an object property from the `tempArray` objects, you are actually deleting it from the `data` objects.

If you want to solve this, you have to destroy the reference by making a deep copy of the objects from the `data` array.

Here is an example how to do it:

```
export const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ id: 1, description: "Test Data" }]);

  const manipulateData = (data) => {
    let tempArray = data.map((item) => {item.description}); //this will create an array with new object, and destroy the reference to the objects of data.
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Testing Data</h1>
      {manipulateData(data)}
      {console.log(data)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Also, instead of deleting a property, better pick the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```js
let tempArray = [...data];
```

only *shallow copies* your `data` array, meaning that any of the objects inside of `tempArray` refer to the same objects in memory that are within the `data` array. This means that when you loop over your objects with `.map()`, each `item` refers to an object from `data` as well, which results in the objects in `data` changing when you use `delete item.id`.

Currently, you are using `.map()` just to loop over your `tempArray`, this isn't the purpose of `.map()`. The `.map()` method returns a new array, and the callback function you pass it should return a new value that you want to map the current value to. This means you can use `.map()` to create `tempArray`, by making the callback function return a new object that excludes the `id` property:

```js
const manipulateData = (data) => {
  const tempArray = data.map(({id, ...rest}) => rest);
  // ... do what you need with `tempArray` ...
};
```

Above, `{id, ...rest}` is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax, which extracts the `id` property from the current element, and stores all other properties/values from the current object in `rest`. This allows you to create a new object that excludes the `id` property.

As a side note, you shouldn't be calling methods such as `console.log()` and `manipulateData()` inside of JSX if they don't return anything meaningful that will be rendered to the screen, instead, you can put these in a `useEffect()` hook.

Comment: Dear Nick,
Thanks for the wonderfull explanation, it has given me great clarification like correct usage of `.map()` and when to apply `useEffect()` hook,

But, while reading the answer, I got another doubt.
In my real project, the `data` / `file` has huge elements, which needs to be manipulated (modify/add/delete).

So as suggested by you, if I shouldn't use `.map()` what shall I do to loop over `tempArray` and to modify it as per my project requirement.

Answer (score 0):

const [data, setData] = useState([{ id: 1, description: "Test Data" }]);

try this

Comment: the information inside "file" variable is dynamic and is being fetched.
so this method is not compatible for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is right in case you are not using a multi-dimensional array, but here you are cloning a multi-dimensional array,
and by using the = operator, it’ll assign objects/arrays by reference instead of by value! That means whenever you modify any of the two objects it's going to affect the value in both.

A good way to solve this is by creating a deep clone by doing something like this

```
    const tempArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...data]))
    tempArray.map((item) => delete item.id)
```